# CSS filter breakes overflow:hidden in Webkit

Tags: css, google-chrome, filter, webkit

So I've come across this weird CSS-issue in Webkit-based browsers (Chrome, Opera, ...). When I apply `overflow:hidden` on a parent div and `filter:grayscale(100%)` (or any other kind of filter), overflow breaks. The elements are not hidden anymore for some reason.

I've tested this on Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Opera. Edge and Firefox don't seem to have this issue, but Chrome and Opera do have it. So I guess it may be an issue with Webkit-based browsers.

[I've made a small video to better illustrate the issue](https://youtu.be/wE4dv9pSNHY) (images in the video may differ from the ones in this post, but the effect is the same. The cursor also appears on the wrong places, but it's actually clicking on the arrows and hovering/clicking on the icons. ShareX does not like high-DPI displays, apparently.)

Does anyone have an idea how I can work around this?

## HTML

```
<div id="projects">
    <img id="left" src="https://i.imgur.com/8u7Kir7.png">
    <div id="scroller">
            <figure><a id="portfolio1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/OU2VsUm.png" alt="BreakingBook"></a></figure>
            <figure><a id="portfolio2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/OU2VsUm.png" alt="BreakingBook"></a></figure>
            <figure><a id="portfolio3"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/OU2VsUm.png" alt="BreakingBook"></a></figure>
            <figure><a id="portfolio4"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/kml3KaY.png" alt="RedAlert"></a></figure>
            <figure><a id="portfolio5"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/kml3KaY.png" alt="RedAlert"></a></figure>
            <figure><a id="portfolio6"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/kml3KaY.png" alt="RedAlert"></a></figure>
    </div>
    <img id="right" src="https://i.imgur.com/RNNpheT.png">
</div>
```

## SCSS

```
#projects {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    img {
        min-width: initial;
        max-width: initial;
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
    }
    #scroller {
        width: 330px;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        border: 5px solid black;
        border-radius: 25px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        figure {
            &:first-of-type {
                margin-left: 20px;
            }
            &:last-of-type {
                padding-right: 40px;
            }
            width: 70px;
            height: 70px;
            margin-right: 40px;
            display: block;
            a {
                filter: grayscale(100%);
                line-height: initial;
                opacity: .3;
                &:hover {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## jQuery

```
$('#projects').find('a').click(function() {
        $('#projects').find('a').not(this).removeAttr('style');
        $(this).css('opacity', '1').css('filter', 'initial');
    });
$('#left').click(function() {
        $('#scroller').animate({ scrollLeft: $('#scroller').scrollLeft() - 330 }, 500);
});    

$('#right').click(function() {
        $('#scroller').animate({ scrollLeft: 330 + $('#scroller').scrollLeft() }, 500);
});
```

Comment: can you provide your HTML w/ links to live images on the web somewhere, not the local relative paths? That's the easiest way for me to test it with exactly what you're working with to be the most help.

Comment: Also, does this include some javascript to make the scrolling happen? That would be useful to get too, as w/ just the html & css you have here, and my own images added, I don't immediately see anything wrong; Nothing stops being hidden on my end. So I'm inclined to believe its whatever makes the forward/backward scrolling happen that might be the culprit?

Comment: Sure, no problem. I've added the missing code. I've also added a short video to better illustrate the issue.

Comment: I've also noticed that the 'tearing' does not occur when either resetting opacity back to 1 or removing the grayscale filter on the anchor tags.

Comment: I can't replicated this in any of my webkit browsers. I'm on Mac OS, newest safari and chrome. I also tried many versions of chrome and opera in windows 10, 8, and 7 via browserstack. I can't determine what might be happening.

Comment: That's weird. I've cleared caches and everything, loaded in in incognito windows. Still the same issue. Oh well, guess I'll just disable either the opacity or grayscale. It won't be that feature-breaking.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway, and sorry if I wasted your time a bit.

Comment: It wasn't a waste of time! this wouldn't be the first case where someone is experiencing a real bug and someone else can't reproduce it :) 

Good luck! hopefully someone else can sort it out